# What happens when I use *(int*)&x to assign to a constant value x?

Tags: c++

I have tried the following codes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct MyClass {
    const int x;
};
int main() {
    MyClass c = {3};
    const int *p = &c.x;

    cout << "x = " << c.x << endl;
    cout << "&x = " << &c.x << endl;
    cout << "p = " << p << endl;
    cout << "*p = " << *p << endl;
    cout << "*(&x) = " << *(&c.x) << endl;
    cout << endl;

    *(int*)&c.x = 4;

    cout << "x = " << c.x << endl;
    cout << "&x = " << &c.x << endl;
    cout << "p = " << p << endl;
    cout << "*p = " << *p << endl;
    cout << "*(&x) = " << *(&c.x) << endl;

    cout << (p == &c.x) << endl;
    cout << (*p == *(&c.x)) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Then I get the following answer:

```
x = 3
&x = 0x61fe98
p = 0x61fe98
*p = 3
*(&x) = 3

x = 4
&x = 0x61fe98
p = 0x61fe98
*p = 4
*(&x) = 4
1
1
```

It seems that I have successfully change the value of constant integer x. But when I directly declare x in main() instead of in a class, I get the totally different answer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int x = 3;
    const int *p = &x;

    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "&x = " << &x << endl;
    cout << "p = " << p << endl;
    cout << "*p = " << *p << endl;
    cout << "*(&x) = " << *(&x) << endl;
    cout << endl;

    *(int*)&x = 4;

    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "&x = " << &x << endl;
    cout << "p = " << p << endl;
    cout << "*p = " << *p << endl;
    cout << "*(&x) = " << *(&x) << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << (p == &x) << endl;
    cout << (*p == *(&x)) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
x = 3
&x = 0x61fe98
p = 0x61fe98
*p = 3
*(&x) = 3

x = 3
&x = 0x61fe98
p = 0x61fe98
*p = 4
*(&x) = 3

1
0
```

That is really strange that (p == &x) is true but (*p == *(&x)) is false!!! I don't know what's going on in the second codes.

Comment: Find a new professor. Don't learn anything else from your current professor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), so anything can happen. The C++ standard says:

> Except that any class member declared `mutable` (10.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a `const` object during its lifetime (6.8) results in undefined behavior.

And:

> *[Note:* Depending on the type of the object, a write operation through the pointer, lvalue or pointer to data member resulting from a `const_cast` that casts away a const-qualifier may produce undefined
>   behavior (10.1.7.1). *— end note]*

So you can cast away the "const" to get `int*` but attempting to actually modify the variable through that pointer is undefined.

The reason you can cast away the `const` is that it might not actually point to a constant:

```
int i = 0;
const int* p = &i;
*(int*)p = 1;      // OK, because p points to a non-constant
const int j = 0;
const int* q = &j;
*(int*)q = 1;      // NOT OK, because q points to a constant
```

In your second example the compiler is making assumptions when optimizing, based on the fact it knows that a constant value will not change, so it doesn't bother testing its value. The assumption is correct because a correct program can never change the value of a constant. Your program is not correct, but that means the compiler isn't required to give a sensible result.